# Plotting a point on the edge of a sphere

Tags: math, 3d

So coming from a flash background I have an OK understanding of some simple 2D trig.  In 2d with I circle, I know the math to place an item on the edge given an angle and a radius using.

```
x = cos(a) * r;
y = sin(a) * r;
```

Now if i have a point in 3d space, i know the radius of my sphere, i know the angle i want to position it around the z axis and the angle i want to position it around, say, the y axis. What is the math to find the x, y and z coordinates in my 3d space (assume that my origin is 0,0,0)?  I would think i could borrow the Math from the circle trig but i can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Your position in 3d is given by two angles (+ radius, which in your case is constant)

```
x = r * cos(s) * sin(t)
y = r * sin(s) * sin(t)
z = r * cos(t)
```

here, **s** is the angle around the z-axis, and **t** is the *height* angle, measured 'down' from the z-axis.

The picture below shows what the angles represent, s=*theta* in the range 0 to 2*PI in the xy-plane, and t=*phi* in the range 0 to PI.

[image]

Comment: Don't forget that `s` and `t` need to be in radians, *not* degrees. To convert to radians: `radians = angleInDegrees * Math.PI / 180`.

Comment: If s=45deg and t=0deg, then (x,y,z) = (0,0,1). But when we actually map it, we would get (0, 0.707, 0.707) right? x and y always give zero when t is zero and z is independent of s...! What should I do to get it right?

Comment: Shouldn't we be able to sweep exactly one circle with t locked down to 0 and varying s? Here, it doesnt work like that, when t is zero, regardless of the value of s, (x,y,z) is always (0,0,1)

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran think about where on the sphere you would be when phi equals zero and you'll realize why this is.

Comment: It's been a year but here are the answers; _x and y always give zero when t is zero and z is independent of s_ **Nope**; _Shouldn't we be able to sweep exactly one circle with t locked down to 0 and varying s?_ **Yes**, but sweeping a circle requires changes in both y and z

Comment: This formula doesn't seem to work correctly, I found this formula making a research, but not sure how to translate it to pseudocode.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1881758/find-point-on-a-sphere-given-two-angles

Comment: Hi, trying to reverse engineer this to find the angle s and t for a given point on a sphere but I'm having a hard time. I seem to be getting `nan`s most of the time. Anyone have any idea how to do this? Thanks

Comment: for s=45deg, t=45deg, is it correct that x=y but z!=x?

Comment: @second How to calculate the radius when the camera is sitting on the ground 4 meters away from where the object is and The camera is tilted 10 degrees upwards towards the sky? is the `radius =4`? how to convert it to pixels?

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer did not seem to support negative x values (possibly I did something wrong), but just in case, using notation from ISO convention on coordinate systems defined in [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Coordinate_system_conversions), this system of equations should work:

```py
import math

x = radius * sin(theta) * cos(phi)
y = radius * sin(theta) * sin(phi)
z = radius * cos(theta)

radius = math.sqrt(math.pow(x, 2) + math.pow(y, 2) + math.pow(z, 2))

phi = math.atan2(y, x)
theta = math.acos((z / radius))
```