# Maths/Python - given a sphere, plot sequential points around the sphere?

Tags: python, math, geometry

I am trying to rotate a vtk camera around its focal point. The aim being to 'orbit' the model.

I'm using the `camera.SetPosiiton(x, y, z)` call to set the camera location, and I know I can do the same at each update period in my render window.

The focal point has the location (0, 0, 0), and some other bounding box getting gives me my initial camera (x, y, z) location. The distance from the focal point (0, 0, 0) to the camera location 9x, y, z) describes the radius the of the sphere.

In my head, this essentially moving the camera in steps around the point (0, 0, 0) and I am presuming there is a maths function I could use to feed it my starting camera point, and work out my next camera location.

This should result in the model appearing to spin in space. My camera view is offset from all x, y, z, planes, making it a 3d problem, not a 2d problem. However, I do want my camera to remain the same distance from the model (focal point)

What I am trying to achieve is like this:- take a pencil (my model is long and narrow). Hold it in your finger tips at arms length, tip pointing to the ceiling. Tilt the pencil by ~30 degrees. This is the camera start position. Rotate the pencil body in your fingers, maintaining tilt angle, and the distance from your eye.

THis post looks helpful: [Plotting a point on the edge of a sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969798/plotting-a-point-on-the-edge-of-a-sphere?rq=1) however, this assumes you know the radius to get to the initial x, y location.

Could some one point me towards the maths I need to do this, my maths is horribly rusty.

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you want is to rotate a vector about an axis, this can be most easily done using a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle)

So, if your desired axis of rotation is tilted 30 degrees from the z axis on the zx plane, your axis of rotation is (cos(pi/6),0,sin(pi/6)), increment the rotation angle, plug that into the [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) to get matrix R, the new camera position vector will be R*(x,y,z)'

Answer (score 0):

Start off with the points (+-1,0,0), (0,+-1,0), (0,0,+-1). These form two Pyramids with all the points on the unit sphere.

Now you can take the midpoints of each triangle, and project out so they lie on the unit sphere too. For each triangle this now gives you 3 new triangles, and you can repeat the process.

The alternative to the midpoint of the triangle is to take the midpoints of each side, and join them up. That gives 3 new points that can be projected out to the unit circle. This gives you 4 triangles for each sub division.

Repeat as many times as you need.

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure that I follow you. :S

Comment: Ok, do you want to orbit the model in a circle or do you want to view it from all sides? If you want to view it from all sides, how often do you want to take a picture?