# Finding point on sphere

Tags: math, trigonometry

So I need to find the point on a sphere's surface using the radius, the center of the circle and the rotation vector. I have this equation right now:

```
x = position.x + radius * Math.cos(rotation.x) * Math.sin(rotation.y)
y = position.y + radius * Math.sin(rotation.x) * Math.sin(rotation.y)
z = position.z + radius * Math.sin(rotation.y)
```

This formula produces crazy results that are totally not what I need at all. I quite honestly have no idea what I've done wrong, I tried to use the formula I found here:
[Finding Point on sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969798/plotting-a-point-on-the-edge-of-a-sphere)

But it didn't work. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You confused degrees and radians.

Comment: Ok... So what do I do? Sorry, I haven't taken a trig class yet, I really don't know much about radians...

Comment: `Radians = Degrees * (2*PI/360)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your third line, you should have the cosine:

```
z = position.z + radius * Math.cos(rotation.y)
```

also, if `rotation.x` and `rotation.y` are given in degrees, you might need to multiply the values by `pi/180` before giving them as arguments to `sin` and `cos`.