# How would i get a point on a sphere?

Tags: c#, math, trigonometry

So im trying to get a point on a sphere via an angle.

```
double X = Math.Cos(pitch * (Math.PI / 180));
double Y = Math.Sin(pitch * (Math.PI / 180)) * Math.Sin(yaw * (Math.PI / 180));
double Z = Math.Sin(pitch * (Math.PI / 180)) * Math.Cos(yaw * (Math.PI / 180));
```

I've tried this, but the point it outputs seems to be clamped to the XZ axis, and increasing/decreasing the yaw doesn't do anything to the point it spits out.

I cant figure out whats wrong with this code? Could someone help me identify the problem?

Comment: Almost seems like more of a math problem than a programming problem. But make sure that you aren't performing floating point arithmetic on integers, e.g. use `180D` instead of just `180`.

Comment: Your example code here in the question looks like a normal bog-standard polar-to-cartesian conversion. You say that _yaw_ doesn't seem to work. Have you checked in the debugger what the value of the _yaw_ variable is when these calculations are being executed?

Comment: @elgonzo The yaw seems to be normal once it goes into the expression, seems exactly what i set it.

Comment: @JohnWu I just didn't want people to get confused with the C# code.

Comment: check this one out https://stackoverflow.com/a/969880/361899

Comment: hope `pitch = <-90,+90>` and `yaw = <0,360>`